# Error while updating dataframe cell value with a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has a column where each cell is list of dictionaries. I want to update this column (each cell) after transforming these lists. I do this task inside a for loop iterating over each row.

```
for index, row in mydf.iterrows():
  to_be_transformed = row['the_column']
  # I transform the values then convert it to a dataframe and then that DF to list of dicts
  transformed_list_in_df_format = transf(to_be_transformed)
  mydf.loc[index,'the_column'] = list(transformed_list_in_df_format.T.to_dict().values())
```

and I am getting

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 611, in _setitem_with_indexer
    raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I tried

```
mydf.loc[index,'the_column'] = mydf.loc[index,'the_column']
```

which gives me the same error. I think there is a fundamental wrong in updating the cell

PS: I could update successfully by using `set_value()`. But afaik, set_value() is deprecated.

```
mydf.set_value(index,'the_column', list(transformed_list_in_df_format.T.to_dict().values()))
```

How to solve this issue? Thank you for the insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set_value has been deprecated, now you can use `at` that can insert a list into a cell. `at` always refers to a single value, while `loc` can refer to values as well as rows and columns.

```
mydf.at[index,'the_column'] = list(transformed_list_in_df_format.T.to_dict().values())
```